# How can I insert '@' inside a lstlisting element in Latex

Tags: latex

I need to insert some text inside a lstlisting element, and my text contains the character '@'.

```
\begin{lstlisting}  some text @ text  \end{lstlisting}
```

Latex gives me an error when I try to do that. I've read its a special character, so how do I escape the character? I tried using ''

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: if I write exactly what I already posted I cannot get the '@' symbol. the "some text text" appears but not the '@' 
\begin{lstlisting}  
@some text  text  
\end{lstlisting}

Comment: Make a compilable [mre]. The code you show works by default, but maybe you have something in your document that alters the default behaviour. We can't read minds, we need to see the code!

Comment: works without problems: https://pastebin.com/2CehMW8C

Comment: Just as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz said, the code works fine. `@` gets typeset. Even though it is a special character (one of its usage is to remove padding, like `@{}`), it doesn't need to be escaped by preceding it with a backslash.

Comment: Yes, please show the minimal code to reproduce the problem :)